# Definite integral with the exponent

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

$$ \int_N^\infty \frac{e^\frac{\Large{-k n^2 \pi^2 t}}{\Large{c l^2}}}{1 - n^2} dn$$

k,t,c,l - const.

Heard about Gaussian integral. I do not know how to use it here. Help me. How to calculate such an integral?

Comment: How is $N$ defined? is the real? greater than zero?

Answer (score 1):

If we let $a=\frac{k\pi^2t}{cl^2}$ we get
$$I=\int_N^\infty\frac{e^{-an^2}}{1-n^2}dn$$
and then the only substitution you could really do is $u=1-n^2$ or try and split $1-n^2$ into $(1+n)(1-n)$
This cannot be expressed using the gaussian integral due to the lower limit but would instead be in terms of the $\text{erfc}(z)$ which is the complementary error function:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

EDIT:

you could also define it in terms of $\Gamma(s,z)$ which is the incomplete gamma function:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: I do not know what to do with the denominator. And how to lead to erfi.

Comment: how did you get this problem?

Comment: I don't know how to use what you gave